# Media query width is not applying to col-md class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Media query width is not applying to col-md class. Below is my code. I am using latest version of Bootstrap.

```
<div class = "col-md-8 article-container-fix">
    <div class = "articles" >
        <article class="clearfix">
            <header>
                line 1
                line 2
                line 3
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
    @media(max-width: 1199px){

       .article-container-fix {

            width: 400px;
            margin-left: 1em;
            background: black;
            color: white;
         }

     }
```

Except width, all three other properties apply to this class ".article-container-fix" but not that "width: 400px". I don't know where I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try it with a bit less **max-width** than 1199, something like 720px to see if it works or not. Other way to output this would be the following

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="article-container-fix">
      Content here!
   </div>
</div>
```

And use the same CSS you used before. It's complicated with bootstrap to actually get some things in place the way you want it, and for this, it could be interfering with pretty much anything. Hopefully this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

ITS Due to you have write your `article-container-fix` class with `col-md-8` class. `col-md-8` is a Bootstrap framework class. By default there is a default width given in **bootstrap.css**.

There is two way to overcome from this problem:

> Either you have to write `!important` in your media query like **width: 400px !important;**
>
> Or
>
> You have to re-positioning your css in your **`<head>`** tag, include most last your responsive.css in your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Thanks the first one worked well, but is there any way to disable the default width given in bootstrap.css.